# Cant get my NSTimer to end when the value <= 0

Tags: ios, nstimer

i cant seem to get my NSTimer to stop when it reaches 0 i've looked around for an answer and i tryed everything please help.

```
-(void)count {
mainint -= 1;
seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", mainint];
}

-(IBAction)start:(id)sender {
play.hidden = YES;
mainint = 60;
timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(count) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
if (timer1 == 0) {
    [timer1 invalidate];
    timer1 = nil;
}
}
```

Comment: You should be checking if mainInt == 0, and the check should be in the count method.

Comment: `if (timer1 == 0)` ==> `if (mainint == 0)` and in `count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your if condition in count() function

```
-(void)count {
    mainint -= 1;
    seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", mainint];
    if (mainint == 0) {
        [timer1 invalidate];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your timer will never be nil (0) unless you set it yourself to nil. I think what you're trying to achieve is something like this :

```
-(void)count {
    mainint -= 1;
    seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", mainint];

    if (mainint <= 0) {
        [timer1 invalidate];
        timer1 = nil;
    }
}
```